# How do I write a math formula?

Tags: ruby, formula

I need to write the following formula in code:

```
C ((i/100)(n/365)+1)
```

This means that `i` should be divided by 100, `n` should be divided by 365, both results must be multiplied, the resulting number should be added 1 and the resulting number should be multiplied by `C`.

I was able to write the following code, but there is an error in the math operation I cannot fix:

```
puts "Insert money to invest:"
money_invested = gets.to_i

puts "Indicate in days the period of deposit:"
time_investment = gets.to_i

puts "Indicate interest rate:"
interest_rate = gets.to_i

investment_calculation = money_invested * (([interest_rate / 100]  [time_investment / 365]) + 1)
puts "Your refund will be $#{investment_calculation.round(2)}."
```

Comment: Why did you think that `[]` would work in math formula in Ruby?

Comment: Why do you have multiplication `*` in one place and nothing in another?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
investment_calculation = money_invested * (((interest_rate / 100) * (time_investment / 365) + 1))
```

1) you used `[]` instead of `()`.

in ruby `[]` corresponds to a list

2) you need to use `*` to multiply the results of `(interest_rate / 100)` and `(time_investment / 365)`

EDIT

If you are using decimals your code wouldn't work, you would need to use `to_f` instead of `to_i`

like this: `interest_rate = gets.to_f`

Comment: I got the following error: "undefined method  '/' for "26.32":String <noMethodError>". 26.32 is the interes rate I've used.

Comment: @Topa_14 If you're calling `to_i` it should definitely not be a string, but if you want to include decimals, use `to_f`.

Comment: @Topa_14 please see the Edit

Comment: Thanks. I've just fixed that bug. However, I'm not able to obtain the proper result now. I just obtain the same amount of money I indicate in `money_invested`.

Comment: did you use `gets.to_f` on `interest_rate` ?

Comment: I've tried the exactly same code you've done, but I'm not getting to the proper result of the operation. I'm getting the same number that in `money_invested`.

Comment: can you tell me which ruby version you are using?

Comment: that's really weird. I tried everything and still can't replicate your error. https://repl.it/B6Ae/0

Comment: In fact yes, you are replicating the error as well. No matter what data you enter, you always reach the same number you've put in answer of  `Insert money to invest`. Try with 1000 and a `interest_rate` of 26.32. The result should be $1021.63. However, we get $1000, instead. There must be something affecting the math operation. Thanks a lot for your support, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide two integers in Ruby, you get integer division (the result is an integer):

```
irb(main):001:0> 1343/1000
#=> 1
```

If you want a floating point number, then you need at least one of the two numbers to be a floating point value:

```
irb(main):002:0> 1343/1000.0
#=> 1.343
irb(main):003:0> 1343.0/1000
#=> 1.343
```

You can do this by making the user input into floating point numbers instead of integers (use `to_f` instead of `to_i`), or by using floating point constants in your formula. The first will suffice, and makes sense, in case the user types in `50.75` for their money. (`"50.75".to_i #=> 50`)

```
puts "Insert money to invest:"
money_invested = gets.to_f

puts "Indicate in days the period of deposit:"
time_investment = gets.to_f

puts "Indicate interest rate:"
interest_rate = gets.to_f

investment_calculation = money_invested * (1 + interest_rate/100 * time_investment/365)
puts "Your refund will be $%.2f." % investment_calculation
```

Note that I've used `String#%` method with `%.2f` to format your number to two decimals. This is because `3.round(2)` yields the number `3.0` and not the string `"3.00"` as you desire.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much for your explanation. It worked fantastically now!